# Distance of time in days

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3 there is `distance_of_time_in_words` which works fine, but I would like to tweak its output a bit.

The thing is that if the dates are exactly the same it will say "Less Than a day" I would like it to show "Today" instead.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a gem called "date-casually" that monkey-patches the Date class with a "casual" method:

```
Date.today.casual
#=> 'today'

(Date.today + 1).casual
#=> 'tomorrow'

(Date.today - 1).casual
#=> 'yesterday'
```

Hope it helps:

http://rubygems.org/gems/date-casually

Comment: Not working for me with Rails 3.2.x and Ruby 1.9.3. Maybe needs a bit of cleaning around the I18n code.